# Kafka connect (sink file not updated)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have updated below properties file according to my requirement

```
connect-standalone.properties 
connect-file-source.properties 
connect-file-sink.properties
```

The Kafka Connect process start and the source connector read lines and write these as messages to the test_topic but messages are not written in `test.sink.txt`

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties
```

Comment: Are all *.properties configurations default ones?